# The relationship between bits and int/float random number generator

Tags: algorithm, random, floating-point, integer, bit

I want to figure out the relationship between bits and RNG for int or float.

(By *random* I mean uniformly distributed)

---

I am given a *perfect* boolean random generator, and I am asked to implement a random 32 bits integer generator (including negative, zero and positive). What I want to do is *generate a random boolean for each of the 32 bits, and concat them together to be a random int*.

Am I doing the right thing?

---

Also from the other way around, if I am given a *perfect* random 32 bits integer generator, can I say each bit can be considered as uniformly distributed over 0 and 1?

---

how about float (not only between 0 and 1, but the full range of float)?

Can I use the same way to generate random IEEE 745 float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are indeed doing it right, using 32 draws of the different numbers, will give you a uniform distributed random variable.

Explanation: Each number can be generated by a unique combination of 32 0/1 draws. No 2 numbers are generated from the same combination, and no number is generated from 2 combinations - meaning, the probability for each number is 1/2^32 - as expected.

---

Yes, Same principle applies here. There are 2^32 'ways' to choose 32 bits number, and similarly to the previous question - you can see that the numbers are independently uniformly distributed on {0,1} per bit.

---

A random uniformly distributed float in range [0,1] can be generated by `randUnsignedInt()/(2^32-1)`. An alternative is drawing an `int` and just re-interpret it ad float - assuming both are using the same number of bits (basically - both are 32 bits number, they only vary in the way you interpret them...) Note that the alternative is NOT in range [0,1].

Comment: If I need to use that perfect boolean random generator, can I apply the same way to generaing float?

Comment: @JacksonTale If you want any float - just create an int and re-interpret it as a float. Note however that it is not 100% uniform because of the floating point arithmetic semantics (More representations to small number than there are for high numbers, in absolute value) - but each float you can represent - will have the exact same probability to be generated - 1/2^32.

Comment: can you have a look at my edit. I really want to find out whether the 32 rounds of random boolean can cover the full float range and each float number is generated uniformly.

Comment: @JacksonTale You will have to define what you mean 'uniformly' for floats. Do you mean each 2 float numbers have the same probability to be chosen? Or for each `a,b,c,d` such that `b-a=d-c` the probability for the number (let it be `x`) be in: `a<x<b` is identical to its probability to be in: `c<x<d`. Due to the floating point representation - the two definitions contradict each other.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last comment. could you please extend your answer to cover the case of float? The uniformly I meant on float is the same concept I meant on int, but under the restriction of precisions. If assume the min float step is 0.1, and max float value is 2, then all floats are -2, -1.9, -1.8, ..., 0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 2. And by uniformly, I mean all those numbers are equally likely appear

Comment: @JacksonTale My answer did cover the case of float. Generate a float in range [0,1] by `randUnsignedInt()/(2^32-1)`, easy to do after we established how to do it with ints. Let the generated number in `[0,1]` be `r`. Now, if you want the range to be [0,2] Just multiply by 2: `myNumber = `r * 2`. If you want it to be in range `[2,5]`, similarly: `myNumber = r*3 + 2`.

Comment: sorry, amit, I understand your solution which utilise int. but I am not seeking for a new way to generate float, but i am wondering whether I can use the same bit random way to generate all floats, i.e., I get 32 random bits, and concat them, can each of the concatenation be a pure random float, covering all possible 32 bits floats

Comment: @JacksonTale  Yes, this is the alternative I am proposing - but note that the probability to get a number `x` such that `0 <= x <= 1` is higher than getting a number such that `2^30 <= x <= 2^30 + 1`, due to the floating point representations - there are more 'small' numbers than 'big' ones according to the standard. However, each 2 possible numbers will have the same probability to be chosen.

Comment: ahhh, ok, I got it. thanks. So can I say that any float number generator cannot really generate pure random all over the float range?

Comment: @amit: For the `float` to have proper distribution (meaning that the probability of its being selected should match the fraction of the range represented thereby), the division must be done as `double`.  Otherwise, the `2^32-1` will get rounded to `2^32`, and some numbers will occur three times as often as those immediately above or below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is exactly what [random.org](https://www.random.org/faq/#Q2.10) does. In this case, the domains are fairly easy to map across -- things like a [6 sided die](https://web.archive.org/web/20171012154111/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65653.html) are harder.

Comment: Are you saying that producing a uniformly random 6-sided dice result is harder than producing a uniformly random float?

Comment: can the `generating 32 random bits way` be applied to float? float has different format of bit representation than integers

Comment: @PascalCuoq Creating a uniformly random integer in the range [0,5] is not trivial to do deterministically with only a bit-generator

Comment: @NiklasB. Maybe, but generating a uniformly random float is **really** difficult. The solutions in the accepted answer have subtle or non-subtle biases. Dividing a random integer by a power of two would be a good start, but would require changing the FPU rounding mode to something other than nearest-even first in order to avoid a bias for “even” floats.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I think this answer here is just referring to the integer generation part. You should rather leave a comment on the other one