# Will IEEE 754 float standard lead to biased distribution on floats?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

For Integers, the bit representation can cover every possible integers between the `min_int` and `max_int`.

For Floats, it is not possible, because between any ranges, the number of floats is infinity.

I understand this, no problem.

The smallest positive float is `min_float`, so I assume any float in PC should theoretically be `k * min_float` and k is an integer, basically, `min_float` is the smallest unit. **am I right?**

---

One comment below https://stackoverflow.com/a/22939681/759076 says

> due to the floating point representations - there are more 'small'
>   numbers than 'big' ones according to the standard.

I can't really understand it. Why there are more small numbers than big ones? IEEE 745 actually categories floats into units, why it will cause this value bias?

Comment: “between any ranges, the number of floats is infinity” You must be thinking of reals. Or rationals. Or dyadics. There is a finite number of floats between +inf and -inf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commenter was correct - there *are* more representable small numbers than big.

For IEEE 754 floating point numbers, you translate the fraction bits into a value in the range 1 ≤ f < 2, then multiply it by the raised exponent. [Wikipedia's explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format%3a_binary64) is pretty good. I'll discuss 64-bit doubles here because it's easy to stick to one type.

For simplicity, let's say the equation is f × 2<sup>e-1023</sup>, ignoring the specifics of how *f* is derived from the raw bits, and the sign bit. For the rest of this answer, assume that the sign bit doesn't exist -  it doesn't actually matter because we're talking about the *magnitude* of values, and not the literal "largeness" or "smallness" in relation to positive and negative numbers.

The important part here is that the exponent data is translated as 2<sup>e-1023</sup>, where *e* is the 11-bit exponent. The possible raw values for *e* are between 0 and 2047, which translates to an exponent range of 2<sup>-1023</sup> to 2<sup>1024</sup>.

<strike>Now, since all fraction values are within the range 1 ≤ f < 2, it holds that there must be 1024 possible values ≤2 for any chosen value of f, and 1024 possible values >2 for any chosen value of f.</strike>

As such, it's relatively trivial to count them:

- 2<sup>52</sup> × 1024 = 4,611,686,018,427,387,904 possible values ≤ 2.
- 2<sup>52</sup> × 1024 = 4,611,686,018,427,387,904 possible values > 2.

**EDIT:** Actually, it's even better than I thought... for any fixed value of f, there are 2048 possible exponent values. When exponent is 1023, the computed exponent (2<sup>1023-1023</sup>) becomes 2<sup>0</sup>, which is 1. Since f × 1 is just f, that means that the 50% bound is *actually* at f, not 2. So for any given value of f, the probability of you randomly picking an exponent that gives you a result less than or equal to f is 50%.

Note that we're considering the *magnitude* of the value, not the literal value, so negatives don't exist here. If you want to bring back the sign bit, just double the counts for each, as you'll have equally many negative numbers with these magnitudes.

Now consider that the range of values in that first set is literally just 0 to f, whereas the range in the second set is f to the maximum possible value that your float type can store. As such, representable numbers will always be a lot more dense in the "small" number range.

To make it 100% clear: 50% of all representable floating point numbers are in the range -f to +f, and all other numbers constitute the remaining 50%.

Comment: Ok, I got it. The possible values for the *mantissa* is fixed and between 1 and 2. The *E* part will increase the whole value by magnitude order, thus the bigger *E* is, the less values it can represent. Just like in decimal system, if I say the *M* part is fixed, assume the only possible values are 1.1 and 1.11, then if we increase the *E* part by 1, the possible values will be 11 and 11.1, but not 11.11; if increase *E* by 2, the possible values are 110 and 111, but not 110.1 or 111.1 or 111.11, etc. So change *E* will lead to more *bigger* values. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: For precise, can you please explain why `Now, since all fraction values are within the range 1 ≤ f < 2, it holds that there must be 1024 possible values ≤2 for any chosen value of f, and 1024 possible values >2 for any chosen value of f.` holds?

Comment: @JacksonTale The situation is complicated by the different treatment of the largest exponent (two infinities and all remaining bit patterns are NaNs) and zero exponent (two zeros all the remaining bit patterns are sub-normal numbers).

Comment: @JacksonTale Pick any random set of 52 bits for the value of `f`. Doesn't matter what they are. How many different floating point values can you make from that single `f` value you picked? The answer is 2^12 (4096), because you have 12 remaining bits: 11 exponent bits and 1 sign bit. If we just look at the exponent - ignoreing the sign for a moment - that's 2048 possible values. Since the computation is 2^(e-1023), that leaves you with 1024 positive exponent values (including zero) and 1024 negative exponent values.

Comment: @JacksonTale Actually, come to think of it, my assertion is wrong - the tipping point is `f`, not 2. That actually makes my argument stronger, though, because `f=2` is the "worst case" for the probability of getting a small number - any other value of `f` would glean you a higher chance of getting a small number.

Comment: @Polynomial You seem to be counting the all-bits-one exponent as representing numbers. It doesn't.

Comment: `When exponent is 1023, the computed exponent (2^1023-1023) becomes 2^0, which is 1. Since f × 1 is just f, that means that the 50% bound is actually at f`, why? why 50% is f?

Comment: if f is fixed, e = 0, shouldn't it be `1/2048`? why `50%`

Comment: No, notice that it's 2^e-1023, so it'll go from 2^-1023 to 2^1023, i.e. 50% each way.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Doesn't matter. If you look at the special cases, the two for 0x7FF result in large or invalid values (inf or NaN) and the two special cases for 0x000 result in signed zero (within the "small" range) and the subnormals range (also small). Since the subnormals count as 2^52 possible states, that counts even more for within-range values.